# Is there a way for a customer of a UWP app to rollback to a previous version?

Tags: win-universal-app, versioning

For Universal Windows apps that are distributed via the Windows Store (i.e. not sideloaded), what should a customer be directed to do if your latest version causes them problems and they would like to essentially "undo" the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the app is updated to the latest version the customer can't take any action to roll back. If it is actually a problem with the app, you'll have to fix it as quickly as possible*, and if it's just a fluke your only option is to do your best to help them get it working again.

*If you are using something like GitHub and using it *correctly*, you should be able to quickly roll out the previous update, essentially "rolling back" the app. Also, if you still have the previous app packages (which you should) you can just re-release them.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience(two years) I think its not possible. Haven't seen it as an option.
If you don't have the package in your packages folder and you have Version control in your project, get an older version of your app and send him the package.

Even better fix the problems. Many of my customers had problems that I solved and works perfect for them.