# Updating already installed sideloaded uwp application

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi, updates, windows-10-iot-core

Is it possible to update sideloaded uwp application on raspberry pi? While coding it I did not think there would be updates so there is nothing prepared for updating in the code. I realized I would like to make one small change, and the application is already installed on multiple devices.

Reason for not just unistalling and reinstalling it again is that during first launch we enter some strings which we store in application data local settings. I would have to come to each raspberry again and re enter these strings if I am to reinstall it completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, OEMs and enterprise customers can deliver app updates to Windows 10 IoT Core devices in the following ways.Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/service/iot/updating-iot-core-apps).

- **Using Microsoft Store:** The app is published and updated from the Microsoft Store
- **Using Device Update Center:** The app is published to Windows Update and updated like any other OEM package (driver package)
- **Using Azure IoT Device Management:** The app is published to Azure Storage and updated through the Azure DM channel New for Windows 10, version 1709
- **Using OMA-DM:** The app is updated using an OMA-DM compliant device management channel such as Intune or System Center Configuration Manager (SCCM)

If you want to update the uwp application from sideload package, you can use [Packagemanager.UpdatePackageAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.updatepackageasync) API to do that. Please refer to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53585879/update-uwp-app-from-usb-drive-on-raspberry-pi). Rita has provided the solution.

Since your app did not include update code, it can not update with sideload package.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So is it possible to update this app on those devices if I use one of the methods you mentioned? Or is it too late now? If it is not possible anymore is there a way to not unistall app local settings why reinstaling the app on raspi?

Comment: @Filip12345, it is too late now. But i think there is a workaround for that, you can change the package name, add the code which can copy the local settings from old package folder which installed.

Comment: I just tried it after the newest portal update. I didnt need to change the package name, just install same package with new version. New version is installed, and local data persists. I am sure it was not possible some months ago, but it is working now.