# Update UWP app in Iot Core version 15063 via USB

Tags: xaml, uwp, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I've created an UWP app in VS2017, that runs in upboard where I've installed Windows Iot Core.
The app's target version is 1803 and min version is Creator Update (Build 15063).
I would like to update the app by clicking button and reading the new appxbundle via USB.

I tried to follow this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53585879/update-uwp-app-from-usb-drive-on-raspberry-pi) but the solution doesn't work.

Note: if I create app packages is not possible to checked the "Enable automatic updates".

Is it possible that this is the cause of my problem?

### EDIT

The update process begins, but nothing happens

Comment: define "doesn't work"

Comment: @DanielA.White the update process begins, but nothing happens.

Comment: Hi Emanuele Leoni, how do you determine "update process begins", what have you seen? Any exception information showed via `Result.Text` if you use the same code with [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53585879/update-uwp-app-from-usb-drive-on-raspberry-pi).

Comment: Hi @RitaHan-MSFT , I suppose that the process begin because there is no exception showed via Result.Text. Instead before I have seen several exceptions when I tried to update

Comment: @EmanueleLeoni What's your windows iot core version of your device and what's kind of your device?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT iot core version is 15603 and the device is an upboard squared. As I asked in my question is it possible that the version does not allow the update?

Comment: @EmanueleLeoni I don't test 15063. You can test 17763 to see if it is version related.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT thank you. Now I'm testing 17763 version, In order to enable the update Do I have to check "Enable automatic updates" or not?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT The `Result.Text` says **the provided package is already installed and reinstallation of the package was blocked**, but I have created a new package in order to install the old that is running in upboard

Comment: @EmanueleLeoni The customer in the article you linked has encounter the same error with yours. You can read the comments in that article.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I solved it follow your instructions. Now It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Result.Text says the provided package is already installed and
>   reinstallation of the package was blocked

This error indicate you are installing the same version with the one has already installed on the device.

To solve this error you need increase the package version:

[image]

The operation will fail if you want to update the app which deployed from Visual Studio. It can only update the app installed with packaged appxbundle. For example, you can install it via device portal, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/appinstaller#using-windows-device-portal) is a document you can reference.