# Update Windows iot core without internet connection

Tags: windows-iot-core-10

We have a Windows iot core device on a network that doesn´t have internet.

We want to update the software running on this device, we have another computer running Windows 10 on the same network, is there some service or software we can install on the Windows 10 computer, so that we can update the application running on iot device.

It should be possible to do the update through code.

Thanks

Anders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, we can update applications on Windows IoT Core via following ways.

- **Using Microsoft Store**
- **Using Device Update Center**
- **Using Azure IoT Device Management**
- **Using OMA-DM**

More details please see this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/service/iot/updating-iot-core-apps#). The first three ways in above list need internet.Using OMA-DM seems an option in your scenario, the OMA-DM interface is supported in Windows 10 IoT Core and any OMA-DM compliant management solution can be used to install and update applications. You may not need a connection to the internet to use license. In this way, you need to configure a [OMA DM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/server-requirements-windows-mdm) server.

In addition, you can also create a custom service for updating the application. You can serve the application package in your server, the devices can load the package's url. And then use [PackageManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager) to update the app.

Here is a topic about [how to update the app from USB drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53585879/update-uwp-app-from-usb-drive-on-raspberry-pi?noredirect=1&lq=1). You can refer to the implement. The difference is packageLocation, in that scenario it is a removable storage, while in your scenario you need to use network share instead.

Comment: What OMA-DM servers exist? I found Funambol but it doesn´t look like you can update the iot device through code there?

Comment: The OMA DM client(here is your Windows IoT Core device) communicates with the server over HTTPS and uses DM Sync (OMA DM v1.2) as the message payload. You need to implement the function via OMA DM protocol.

Comment: We went the package manger way there is an example here.https://matthijs.hoekstraonline.net/2016/09/27/auto-updater-for-my-side-loaded-uwp-apps/